# upload csv file in database but last filed add one more data blank

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am upload csv file in database it's done but when i upload csv file and show data table than it is upload one more row in table.
like i am upload 10 data but insert 11 row in data table.

```
 // path where your CSV file is located
define('csvfile/',
        'plivo/dialer/csvfile/');
  // Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = $target_dir . "$file";
if (($handle = fopen($csv_file,
        "r")) !== FALSE) {
    fgetcsv($handle);
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,
    1000,
    ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c = 0;
                $c < $num;
                $c++) {
            $col[$c] = $data[$c];
        }
       echo '<br>'. $col1 = $col[0];
        echo 'data'.$col1.'<br>';
        if($col1 != ' ' || $col1 != NULL){
            // SQL Query to insert data into DataBase
       $query = "INSERT INTO callblast(`callerid`, `phoneno`, `playurl`,`campaignid`) VALUES('$caller_id','" . $col1 . "','$play_url','$row_id')";
        print_r("INSERT INTO callblast(`callerid`, `phoneno`, `playurl`,`campaignid`) VALUES('$caller_id','" . $col1 . "','$play_url','$row_id')");
        $s = mysql_query($query);
        if ($s) {
            echo 'pass';
            header("location:dashboard.php");
        } else {
            echo 'fail<br>';
        }
        }            
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

when i am print query show

```
 1data1
 INSERT INTO callblast(`callerid`, `phoneno`, `playurl`,`campaignid`) VALUES('9988776655','1','www.test.com','15')

2data2
INSERT INTO callblast(`callerid`, `phoneno`, `playurl`,`campaignid`) VALUES('9988776655','2','www.test.com','15')

3data3
INSERT INTO callblast(`callerid`, `phoneno`, `playurl`,`campaignid`) VALUES('9988776655','3','www.test.com','15')

4data4
INSERT INTO callblast(`callerid`, `phoneno`, `playurl`,`campaignid`) VALUES('9988776655','4','www.test.com','15')

5data5
INSERT INTO callblast(`callerid`, `phoneno`, `playurl`,`campaignid`) VALUES('9988776655','5','www.test.com','15')

data
INSERT INTO callblast(`callerid`, `phoneno`, `playurl`,`campaignid`) VALUES('9988776655','','www.test.com','15')
```

last data was like this added

what is issue for more row add in database.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: add the file that you tried to upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall check `$col1 != ' '` this way: `trim($col1) != ''`, cause the last line of file contains EOF/EOL and more spaces/tabs.

Comment: Good luck!
In case you expect only digits (integer) in your `$col1`, you should use `intval()` function before insert into database.